# Jenkins pipeline how to detect downstream build status when using parallel()?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline that invokes a couple hundred runs of a downstream job in a parallel block. The downstream job contains a check that may abort the job.

How can I check the build status of the downstream jobs ran in the parallel block? Ideally, the parallel step returns the status of each downstream build in a map or something, but as far as I can tell it returns only a single build status. In my case, if downstream jobs have been SUCCESS, FAILURE, and ABORTED, the upstream build sets it's status as ABORTED.

`currentBuild.status` and `currentBuild.currentResult` both seem to have the wrong status set, and if I catch the exception thrown from the parallel step, it's just a hudson control flow exception that doesn't let me know the status of the downstream build.

What is the best way to get the correct downstream build status from jobs invoked from the parallel step?

Comment: When you invoke the downstream job you probably use the `build` step inside the parallel block section. when using the `build` command it returns a map of the build execution result which you can use to retrive the status you need.

Comment: Can I store the map that each `build` command returns in a list and then check the list? I have quite a few downstream builds that run, and am worried about concurrency (appending to the list for every downstream build that runs in parallel).

Comment: Yes you can create a global map, store all the parallel results in it. and parse the results later on in the code.